# 'last seen 'for whatsapp contact not showing anymore?Am I being blocked?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there any reason that I am not able to see a whatsapp contact's last seen time anymore?Such as some kind of bug but not being blocked?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on which version of WhatsApp you currently operate

1. In the previous versions of WhatsApp you had to block a specified
   user in order to avoid your last seen, display picture be seen from
   an annoying person.
2. If you have been blocked by a person then after few days you will
   not be able to view their dp as well as last seen.
3. In the latest version(s) WhatsApp provides more privacy
   settings. These are available via Settings > Account > Privacy (in both Android and iOS).
4. **Hide display picture**-If you select this option then urs as well as
   other display picture will be hidden (i.e your dp will be hidden from others as
   well as you cannot view other's dp as well).
5. **Hide last seen**-If you select this option then your last seen will
   not be visible to anyone as well as you cannot see other's last seen.
6. How ever if you are not sure then better wait for few days(1-2)
   after which you can yourself identify whether you have been blocked
   by some person or its your settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see "last seen at" stamp it could mean you've been blocked, but if a contact has blocked you, you should also not be able to check the updates to the contact's profile picture and you'll no more see the second check mark ("message delivered") in the messages you send to that contact, Whatsapp will only print the first one (which is for "message sent").

If you don't see any of these indicators there could be many reasons: Whatsapp is vaguous on this point for privacy policy, i.e. Whatsapp won't let a contact be sure you have blocked him. In your case, you have probably encontered a temporary effect of this.

Comment: There are apps that deliberately block the 'last online' feature of Whatsapp. Most don't work but it is at least possible that the person is using this also.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the new whatsapp update provide user to hide the last seen stamp. In `Settings->Account->Privacy` you will find option to hide. But if you enable this option you cant see other peoples timestamp too